# What is the difference between HD Node and Wallet in ethers.js?

Tags: wallets, ethers.js, addresses, hd-wallets

I am now implementing HD Wallet using ethers.js library.

And I noticed something strange.

```js
async function getWalletFromMnemonic(mnemonic: string): Promise<Wallet> {
    return ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
}

async function getHDNodeFromMnemonic(mnemonic: string): Promise<HDNode> {
    return ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
}
```

The above two function returns different address and privateKey from the same mnemonic.

> How is this possible?
> Can you tell me exactly how your wallet and HD Node are conceptually different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this `ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic)` generate only one account

You can read from [hd wallet Bip32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki)

> The Bitcoin reference client uses randomly generated keys. In order to
> avoid the necessity for a backup after every transaction, (by default)
> 100 keys are cached in a pool of reserve keys. Still, these wallets
> are not intended to be shared and used on several systems
> simultaneously. They support hiding their private keys by using the
> wallet encrypt feature and not sharing the password, but such
> "neutered" wallets lose the power to generate public keys as well.

I think this is the most important advantage:

> Deterministic wallets do not require such frequent backups, and
> elliptic curve mathematics permit schemes where one can calculate the
> public keys without revealing the private keys. This permits for
> example a webshop business to let its webserver generate fresh
> addresses (public key hashes) for each order or for each customer,
> without giving the webserver access to the corresponding private keys
> (which are required for spending the received funds).
>
> However, deterministic wallets typically consist of a single "chain"
> of keypairs. The fact that there is only one chain means that sharing
> a wallet happens on an all-or-nothing basis. However, in some cases
> one only wants some (public) keys to be shared and recoverable. In the
> example of a webshop, the webserver does not need access to all public
> keys of the merchant's wallet; only to those addresses which are used
> to receive customer's payments, and not for example the change
> addresses that are generated when the merchant spends money.
> Hierarchical deterministic wallets allow such selective sharing by
> supporting multiple keypair chains, derived from a single root.

There are further improvements BIP44,BIP49, BIP84. [you can read](https://river.com/learn/terms/b/bip-44-derivation-paths-for-p2pkh/)

[image]

Comment: The wallet created by ```ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic``` is a neutered wallet, and ```ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(mnemonic)``` is a deterministic wallet. 

A neutered wallet can hide the private key, but it also loses the power to generate a public key. 

A deterministic wallet can generate a public key while hiding the private key, thus it can generate a child wallet.

Is it correct that I understand? @Yilmaz

Comment: correct. from child wallet you can grandchild wallets. I should put an image to be more descriptive

Comment: You're so kind! Thanks to you, I completely understand.